# Running "mvn archetype:generate" stalls

Tags: windows-7, maven

When I try to run the command `mvn archetype:generate` it stalls when trying to download ***maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.jar***

No matter how many times I cancel the batch process or close cmd and restart, it still stops at the same point when I try again. The last attempt produced the following result:

> d:\Workshop\dev\java\projects\default\spring-test-web>mvn archetype:generate
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assemb
>   ly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.jar
>   65 KB

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm using Windows 7 and Maven v3.0.3 which as far as I know is installed correctly.

Comment: I am having exactly same problem. I would appreciate if you can let us know whether you found any solution !

Answer (score 1):

Check if your development machine needs a HTTP proxy to access the internet - you might be able to establish this by checking your browser settings.

If you find you need a proxy server, see [Maven - Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem on Windows Vista with just about everything Maven might want to download.

If I'm lucky can usually get around it by killing Maven (CTRL+C) and then re-running whatever task I was trying to do. Since Maven will only download the stuff once, the problem doesn't matter unless I'm using a plugin for the first time

*UPDATE (V2)*

I have this problem at work, but not at home.
I have AVG at work and not at home - at home I have Avast.

It works fine with the Link Scanner and Online Shield components disabled - your mileage may vary

Comment: I had the same problem too. Reading pal's answer, I temporarily disabled my anti-virus program (have AVG) and it resumed download of files without having to re-run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same problem and had AVG running virus check.
Temporarilly disabling it and restarting the mvn command worked perfectly.

Comment: your my hero.  I've been pulling my hair out for days!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with adding proxy in setings file in maven configuration.
Just add something like this:

```
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
      <host>proxy.yourHost</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>yourHost</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

Comment: What are expected values here? Can you please describe so that I can decide them for my machine.